# Bug in downloading a text file in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have download text file request from backend. I need to download the file by posting get request given in `service.js` but the problem is I am getting %7d %7d in blank when I am downloading the file. Need assistance.I even tried with ng-href, still no luck

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="downloadAllExhibitors();">
<a href="{{newFile}}" target="_blank">Download</a></button>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.downloadAllExhibitors = function () {
    $scope.newFile = service.downloadExhibitor(); 
     }
```

Service.js

```
   var url =' http://localhost/1290/';
  function downloadExhibitor() {


            var token = 129821sahh;
            var auth = "Token" + ' ' + token;

            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': auth
                }
            }

       return $http.get(url + 'entity/campaigns/download_exhibitors/', config);
        }
```

Comment: `$http.get` returns a Promise. Try `service.downloadExhibitor().then((res) => {$scope.newFile = res.data;})`. Also your `%7d %7d` are URL encoded `}}`

Comment: i don't see any download code here

Comment: @AlekseySolovey if i give that way, I am getting response like this {"data":"id\tname\temail\tphone\twebsite\tvenue\ttags\n sunitha\tsunitha@gmail.com\t55555541\thttp://www.sunitha.com\n,"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","headers":{"Authorization":"Token 13946cc6c575d61b042b01b6905f1d239b3d9b08","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"url":"http://localhost/1290/"},"statusText":"OK","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Comment: Why are you using `application/json` if it is a text file? Why are you setting the `href` attribute with `{{ }}` interpolation if the data is JSON?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code lies in 
`$scope.newFile = service.downloadExhibitor();` Since `$http.get` is `async` and returns a `promise`, you can always define `callback`s to handle the `success`/`error` response from `server`.

So, by the time your `server` returns the `response` you have no actions defined to handle it. Your service can be re-written as :-

```
var url =' http://localhost/1290/';
function downloadExhibitor() {

        var token = 129821sahh;
        var auth = "Token" + ' ' + token;

        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': auth
            }
        }

        return $http.get(url + 'entity/campaigns/download_exhibitors/', config)
               .then(successHandler, errorHandler);
}

function successHandler(response){
    /* we've got file's data from server */
    return response.data;
}

function errorHandler(error){
    /* we've got error response from server */
    throw new Error('ERROR ' + error);
}
```

and eventually the `service` invocation

```
$scope.newFile = "";
service.downloadExhibitor()
       .then(function(data){
                $scope.newFile = data;
             }, function(error){ 
                console.log(error);
             });
```

Comment: I tried same method. Still I am getting this error only Cannot GET /Organizer/idnameemailphonewebsitevenuetags83Any%20Namea@b.com9009009009http://www.anyname.comHall%20Atag1,%20tag2,%20tag3sunithasunitha@gmail.com55555541http://www.sunitha.comSuhasinisuha@gmail.com955555544http://www.suha.comRaichelraichel@gmail.com955548458http://www.raichel.com